# How/where to stop Django Formwizards 'done' method being called on payment failure

Tags: django, validation, call, formwizard

I've looked through the django documentation, done lots of googling and have tried quite a few different solutions but to no avail.

I've created a 3 part form using Django's FormWizard. Once the last form (a payment form) is validated, I send a payment request to a payment gateway.

I'm doing the payment processing in the 'process_step' method of the FormWizard.

I'm having difficulty figuring out how to have the FormWizard show the payment page again when the payment fails. As it is now, the FormWizard's 'done' method gets called (after I've done my processing in process_step), as all of the forms have been validated.

I'm wondering if I need to override the **call** method. Not really sure how to do that, but I'm currently trying to figure that out.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Regards,
Shawn

```
class TrainingWizard(FormWizard):

def process_step(self,request,form,step):
    if step == 0:
        self.extra_context = {'stepOne': "One"}
    if step == 1:
        self.extra_context = {'stepTwo': "Two"}
    if step == 2:
        if self.get_response != "Success":
            #Payment Failed
            #Add error message
            #Show Payment Form Again to allow user to retry     
    return

def get_response(self):
    #return "Success"
    return "Declined"

def done(self, request, form_list):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/training-registration-complete/')
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something fundamental in the way Forms are processed with FormWizard. 

What I want to do is something like the comments in step==2 of process_step (as shown in the test code). Just not sure what code to put there. 

No matter what I put in there, the done method seems to get executed as the last form has been validated. 

If anyone could provide a line of code that would work there to show the payment form again (x number of times until the payment succeeds), or suggest something I could do in render_template or elsewhere, it would be a great help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally hit upon a solution.  I'm using the SessionWizardView class in Django 1.4.

I overrode the render_done() function (copied it directly out of django/django/contrib/formtools/wizard/views.py and tweaked it.

Between 'final_form_list.append(form_obj)' and the last three lines (starting with 'done_response = self.done(final_form_list, **kwargs)') I handle talking with the payment gateway.

If there's an error, I redirect back to the last step in the form (using self.render.revalidation_failure()) and they can try again.

Here's a snippet of code:

```
try:
    charge = stripe.Charge.create(
        amount=price_in_cents,
        currency="usd",
        card=token,
        description="BlahStore Order Number: %s" %(self.order.pk),
    )
except (stripe.APIConnectionError, stripe.APIError, stripe.AuthenticationError, stripe.CardError, stripe.InvalidRequestError, stripe.StripeError) as e:
    from django.forms import forms
    from django.forms.util import ErrorList
    errors = final_form_list[3]._errors.setdefault(forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, ErrorList())
    errors.append(e.message)
    return self.render_revalidation_failure(3, final_form_list[3], **kwargs)
```

You'll notice I have '3' hard-coded in a few places--this is because my wizard has four steps and the array is zero based.  I set the error message to display and then redirect.  I'm sure it would be fairly easy to adapt this if you wanted to stick with process_step(), but I personally think TheRightWay is to override the render_done() function.

Answer (score 0):

The FormWizard is aware of field validation but anything outside that, such as credit card processing is up to your view (or elsewhere) to catch and respond to.

Since the form validated, and you now have a POST of the users input, each exception/result in your view can render to the page (w/ RequestContext on) and also add to it your error messages  . Same should apply to forms.py.

Comment: Hi Flowpoke, thanks for the response. I'm still not quite clear on this. I'm not sure how to stay within the form wizard's processing when the payment fails on the last step. Could you take a look at the additional comments I've added and possibly provide a bit more detail, or a line of code to help out. In the meantime, I'll keep working at it. Cheers.